# Running a function to change images every time <h4> reaches middle of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm completely blocked with this issue. I need to run a function which changes the image every time my `h4` reaches the middle of window. In my case, one image per `h4`, changing it when user scrolls down or scrolls up. That's to say, each `img` will belong to a `h4`. Up to now, I've achieved change the opacity per `h4` but I don't get change the image. Here's my html:

```
<div id="column-left">
  <h4 class="active">Targets</h4>
  <h4>Valors</h4>
  <h4>Me </h4>
</div>

<div id="column-right">
    <img src="img/about/map.jpg" class="active" alt="Map"/>
    <img src="img/about/bridge.jpg" alt="Bridge"/>
    <img src="img/about/road.jpg" alt="Road"/>
</div>
```

Here's my code:

```
var findMiddleElement = (function(docElm){
var viewportHeight = docElm.clientHeight,
    elements = $('h4');
$('h4').first().css('opacity','1','important');
return function(e){
    var middleElement;
    if( e && e.type == 'resize' )
        viewportHeight = docElm.clientHeight;

    elements.each(function(){
        var pos = this.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        // if an element is more or less in the middle of the viewport
        if( pos > viewportHeight/2.5 && pos < viewportHeight/1.5 ){
            middleElement = this;
            console.log('I am in the middle');
            changeImage();
            return false; // stop iteration 

        }
    });

    $(middleElement).css({opacity:'1', transition : 'opacity 1s ease-in-out'});

}
})(document.documentElement);

$(window).on('scroll resize', findMiddleElement);

function changeImage(){
    console.log('I am ready to change the image');
    $('img').each(function(){
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
}
```

And here's the fiddle: 
[jsfiddle.net/antoniobarcos/owv1ysto/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/antoniobarcos/owv1ysto/4/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does all of the script run? as in when you go into chrome for instance and see the console are there any errors being flagged?
also a js fiddle would make this allot clearer, I'll try put one together now out of your code.

Comment: @arg0 Yes, I've tried and all is running except for the changeImage function. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/antoniobarcos/owv1ysto/4/ As you can see, the opacity of <h4> changes but not image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `changeImage()` just assigns the `active` class to the last image element on the page. You don't have any css rule, regarding the behaviour of that class on an image element, so obviously it does not affect anything. I see two possible solutions:

1. Send the index of the current `h4` element (you are looping through them) to the `changeImage` function and select the `img:nth-child(idx + 1)` element to apply the `active` class. It would also require some css like `img { display: none; } img.active { display: block; }`. In my opinion this is not very flexible.
2. Add some attribute, e.g. `data-image`, with the source for the image, corresponding to each of `h4` element. Then, you would have only one image element in the right-column and your code would look like something similar to this:

```js
/* CHANGE MI IMAGE PLEASE */

var findMiddleElement = (function(docElm) {
  var viewportHeight = docElm.clientHeight,
    elements = $('h4');
  $('h4').first().css('opacity', '1', 'important');
  return function(e) {
    var middleElement;
    if (e && e.type == 'resize') viewportHeight = docElm.clientHeight;

    elements.each(function(idx) {
      var pos = this.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      // if an element is more or less in the middle of the viewport
      if (pos > viewportHeight / 2.5 && pos < viewportHeight / 1.5) {
        middleElement = this;
        console.log('I am in the middle');
        changeImage($(this).data('image'));
        return false; // stop iteration 

      }
    });

    $(middleElement).css({
      opacity: '1',
      transition: 'opacity 1s ease-in-out'
    });

  };
})(document.documentElement);

$(window).on('scroll resize', findMiddleElement);

// You probably don't need a function with one line
function changeImage(src) {
  console.log('I am ready to change the image');
  $('img').attr('src', src);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000;
}
h4 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.left-column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.right-column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
}
.right-column img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
h4 {
  opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-column">
  <h4 data-image="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/dam/assets/130530161523-100-beaches-crane-beach-horizontal-gallery.jpg"> Targets </h4>

  <p>Nunc vitae turpis sem. Aliquam augue ligula, lacinia quis massa volutpat, fermentum ornare quam. Donec lacinia lorem orci, sit amet facilisis arcu posuere eu. Proin eu mauris ligula. Pellentesque fringilla, nisl eu ullamcorper hendrerit, nisl neque
    auctor turpis, nec placerat justo massa vel erat. Vestibulum quis metus et tellus feugiat hendrerit. Nunc volutpat in turpis id imperdiet. Duis odio massa, maximus at pulvinar eu, semper sed eros. Praesent consectetur eros a neque accumsan, at semper
    libero pharetra. Sed tempor, nunc quis gravida congue, lacus nisi aliquam urna, sed hendrerit risus risus eget ipsum. Vivamus eu consequat risus. Fusce tempus rhoncus odio non gravida. Nunc in ante lacus.</p>
  <h4 data-image="http://www.jeremynoeljohnson.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/mountain.jpg"> Valors </h4>

  <p>Maecenas sollicitudin ligula nibh, at rutrum leo sagittis non. Sed quis ornare elit, eget sodales quam. Suspendisse arcu elit, rhoncus vel neque a, faucibus aliquam massa. Mauris tincidunt dui a ipsum suscipit malesuada. Donec lacus justo, porttitor
    vel vehicula in, placerat rutrum mi. Etiam non fermentum massa, nec congue justo. Duis sed ex molestie, varius tellus sit amet, molestie nunc. Phasellus aliquam magna nunc, ut lacinia massa egestas molestie. Nullam fringilla porta massa sed rhoncus.
    Curabitur non ullamcorper odio, eu feugiat urna. Integer a mattis magna, in sollicitudin arcu. Fusce consectetur eu orci at sagittis. Maecenas vel ligula consectetur, placerat nibh quis, gravida augue. In risus ex, volutpat in risus at, efficitur
    congue urna. Sed posuere mollis consectetur.</p>
  <h4 data-image="http://collabcubed.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/high-trestle-trail-bridge_kevin_eberle_booneiowa_collabcubed.jpg"> Me </h4>

  <p>Maecenas sollicitudin ligula nibh, at rutrum leo sagittis non. Sed quis ornare elit, eget sodales quam. Suspendisse arcu elit, rhoncus vel neque a, faucibus aliquam massa. Mauris tincidunt dui a ipsum suscipit malesuada. Donec lacus justo, porttitor
    vel vehicula in, placerat rutrum mi. Etiam non fermentum massa, nec congue justo. Duis sed ex molestie, varius tellus sit amet, molestie nunc. Phasellus aliquam magna nunc, ut lacinia massa egestas molestie. Nullam fringilla porta massa sed rhoncus.
    Curabitur non ullamcorper odio, eu feugiat urna. Integer a mattis magna, in sollicitudin arcu. Fusce consectetur eu orci at sagittis. Maecenas vel ligula consectetur, placerat nibh quis, gravida augue. In risus ex, volutpat in risus at, efficitur
    congue urna. Sed posuere mollis consectetur.</p>
</div>
<div class="right-column">
  <img src="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/dam/assets/130530161523-100-beaches-crane-beach-horizontal-gallery.jpg" />
</div>
```

Note that when you scroll back up, the image won't change to the first one, since the first `h4` element is not in the middle. You should fix that case, if it is not desired behaviour.

Comment: That is. In my case I have to change the image even though the user scrolls back but the script is fine now. Thank you so much.